# Задаю переменную int, а питон говорит мне что она list. Не получается написать алгоритм Кнутта-Морриса-Пратта

Tags: python, алгоритм

Пытался сам разобраться в написании алгоритма Кнута-Морриса-Пратта на питоне и столкнулся с проблемой, обойти которую мне не по силам.
Первая функция ищет префикс-функцию и в целом работает, а вторая собственно сам алгоритм. Проверить это дело я пытась последним куском кода.

```
def pref_suff(A):
    P = [0]*len(A)
    for i in range (1, len(A)):
        j = P[i-1]
        while j > 0 and A[i] != A[j]:
            j = P[j-1]
        if A[i]==A[j]:
            j+=1
        P[i]=j
    return [P]
```

```
def kmp(A, B):
    P = pref_suff(B)
    j = 1
    for i in range (len (A)):
        while A[i]!=B[j] and j > 0:
            j = P[j-1]
        if A[i]==B[j]:
            j+=1
            if j==len(B):
                return True
        else:
            if i == len(A)-len(B)+1:
                return False
```

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4]
F = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4]
c = kmp(A, F)
print (c)
```

И в итоге столкнулся с тем, что в алгоритме КМП переменна j определяется как list и я не могу уйти от цикла while потому что банально не могу сравнить её с нулём или найти B[j].
Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: return [P] замените на return P в первой функции.у вас там получался список списков и на 4й итерации j становился списком в j = P[j-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def pref_suff(A):
    P = [0]*len(A)
    for i in range (1, len(A)):
        j = P[i-1]
        while j > 0 and A[i] != A[j]:
            j = P[j-1]
        if A[i]==A[j]:
            j+=1
        P[i]=j
    return [P]    <-ошибка тут
```

ваша ошибка заключается в return [P], тут возвращается список списков изза чего далее и происходит сбой. замените это на return P

```
def pref_suff(A):
    P = [0]*len(A)
    for i in range (1, len(A)):
        j = P[i-1]
        while j > 0 and A[i] != A[j]:
            j = P[j-1]
        if A[i]==A[j]:
            j+=1
        P[i]=j
    return P
```

Comment: Починилось, большое спасибо!

Comment: примите пожалуйчта ответ- с лева нажмите галочку